# How to add new tokens to an existing Huggingface tokenizer?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, large-language-model

## How to add new tokens to an existing Huggingface AutoTokenizer?

Canonically, there's this tutorial from Huggingface https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter6/2 but it ends on the note of "quirks when using existing tokenizers". And then it points to the `train_new_from_iterator()` function in Chapter 7 but I can't seem to find reference to how to use it to extend the tokenizer without re-training it.

**I've tried** the solution from [Training New AutoTokenizer Hugging Face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974438/training-new-autotokenizer-hugging-face) that uses `train_new_from_iterator()` but that will re-train a tokenizer, but it is not extending it, the solution would replace the existing token indices. [Training New AutoTokenizer Hugging Face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974438/training-new-autotokenizer-hugging-face)

```
import pandas as pd

def batch_iterator(batch_size=3, size=8):
        df = pd.DataFrame({"note_text": ['foobar', 'helloworld']})
        for x in range(0, size, batch_size):
            yield df['note_text'].to_list()

old_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
training_corpus = batch_iterator()
new_tokenizer = old_tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(training_corpus, 32000)

print(len(old_tokenizer))
print(old_tokenizer( ['foobarzz', 'helloworld'] ))
print(new_tokenizer( ['foobarzz', 'hello world'] ))
```

[out]:

```
50265
{'input_ids': [[0, 21466, 22468, 7399, 2], [0, 20030, 1722, 39949, 2]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]}
{'input_ids': [[0, 275, 2], [0, 276, 2]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]}
```

**Note:** The reason why the new tokens starts from 275 and 276 is because there are reserved tokens from ids 0-274.

The expected behavior of `new_tokenizer( ['foo bar', 'hello word'] )` is to have IDs beyond the tokenizer vocab size (i.e. 50265 for the `roberta-base` model) and it should look like this:

```
{'input_ids': [[0, 50265, 2], [0, 50266, 2]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]}
```

Comment: There's this question that asks on `BertTokenizerFast` which is similar but not the same as `AutoTokenizer`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669365/huggingface-bert-tokenizer-add-new-token

Answer (score 4):

## Extending existing AutoTokenizer with new tokens

**Source:** https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/how-to-add-new-tokens-to-huggingface-transformers/

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

# pick the model type
model_type = "roberta-base"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_type)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_type)

# new tokens
new_tokens = ["new_token"]

# check if the tokens are already in the vocabulary
new_tokens = set(new_tokens) - set(tokenizer.vocab.keys())

# add the tokens to the tokenizer vocabulary
tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))

# add new, random embeddings for the new tokens
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

#### Adding emojis to tokenizer

Here's an example usage, first get a list of emojis from a `emoji.txt` file, [Printing out all unicode emojis to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595197/printing-out-all-unicode-emojis-to-file)

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

# pick the model type
model_type = "bert-base-multilingual-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_type)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_type)

# add emojis
new_tokens = [e.strip() for e in open('emoji.txt')] 

# check if the tokens are already in the vocabulary
new_tokens = set(new_tokens) - set(tokenizer.vocab.keys())

# add the tokens to the tokenizer vocabulary
tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))

# add new, random embeddings for the new tokens
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

#### Adding multi-word expressions to tokenizer

Here's an example to extract multi-words expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76058924/610569

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers.pipelines.token_classification import TokenClassificationPipeline

model_checkpoint = "Davlan/bert-base-multilingual-cased-ner-hrl"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)


class TokenClassificationChunkPipeline(TokenClassificationPipeline):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def preprocess(self, sentence, offset_mapping=None, **preprocess_params):
        tokenizer_params = preprocess_params.pop("tokenizer_params", {})
        truncation = True if self.tokenizer.model_max_length and self.tokenizer.model_max_length > 0 else False
        inputs = self.tokenizer(
            sentence,
            return_tensors="pt",
            truncation=True,
            return_special_tokens_mask=True,
            return_offsets_mapping=True,
            return_overflowing_tokens=True,  # Return multiple chunks
            max_length=self.tokenizer.model_max_length,
            padding=True
        )
        #inputs.pop("overflow_to_sample_mapping", None)
        num_chunks = len(inputs["input_ids"])

        for i in range(num_chunks):
            if self.framework == "tf":
                model_inputs = {k: tf.expand_dims(v[i], 0) for k, v in inputs.items()}
            else:
                model_inputs = {k: v[i].unsqueeze(0) for k, v in inputs.items()}
            if offset_mapping is not None:
                model_inputs["offset_mapping"] = offset_mapping
            model_inputs["sentence"] = sentence if i == 0 else None
            model_inputs["is_last"] = i == num_chunks - 1
            yield model_inputs

    def _forward(self, model_inputs):
        # Forward
        special_tokens_mask = model_inputs.pop("special_tokens_mask")
        offset_mapping = model_inputs.pop("offset_mapping", None)
        sentence = model_inputs.pop("sentence")
        is_last = model_inputs.pop("is_last")

        overflow_to_sample_mapping = model_inputs.pop("overflow_to_sample_mapping")

        output = self.model(**model_inputs)
        logits = output["logits"] if isinstance(output, dict) else output[0]


        model_outputs = {
            "logits": logits,
            "special_tokens_mask": special_tokens_mask,
            "offset_mapping": offset_mapping,
            "sentence": sentence,
            "overflow_to_sample_mapping": overflow_to_sample_mapping,
            "is_last": is_last,
            **model_inputs,
        }

        # We reshape outputs to fit with the postprocess inputs
        model_outputs["input_ids"] = torch.reshape(model_outputs["input_ids"], (1, -1))
        model_outputs["token_type_ids"] = torch.reshape(model_outputs["token_type_ids"], (1, -1))
        model_outputs["attention_mask"] = torch.reshape(model_outputs["attention_mask"], (1, -1))
        model_outputs["special_tokens_mask"] = torch.reshape(model_outputs["special_tokens_mask"], (1, -1))
        model_outputs["offset_mapping"] = torch.reshape(model_outputs["offset_mapping"], (1, -1, 2))

        return model_outputs


pipe = TokenClassificationChunkPipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")

mwe_tokens = set(
  token['word'] for sent in pipe(
    ["Bernard works at BNP Paribas in Paris.", "In New York, you will be a New Man"]) 
  for token in sent
)


# pick the model type
model_type = "bert-base-multilingual-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_type)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_type)

# check if the tokens are already in the vocabulary
new_tokens = set(mwe_tokens) - set(tokenizer.vocab.keys())

# add the tokens to the tokenizer vocabulary
tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))

# add new, random embeddings for the new tokens
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

## Extending existing AutoTokenizer with new bpe-tokenized tokens

```
from datasets import load_dataset

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

# pick the model type
model_type = "bert-base-multilingual-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_type)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_type)

# Original vocab size.
print(len(tokenizer))
# Note the outputs are 100s indices which points to unknown tokens.
print(tokenizer("የቀን 7 ሰዓት አማርኛ ዜና ሚያዝያ"))


# Take the first 1000 sentences from cc100. 
am_dataset = load_dataset("cc100", "am")
am_train = iter(am_dataset['train'][i]['text'] for i in range(1000))

# Train a new tokenizer using the am_train and the old tokenizer object.
new_tokenizer = tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(am_train, vocab_size=100_000)

tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokenizer.vocab))

print(new_tokenizer("የቀን 7 ሰዓት አማርኛ ዜና ሚያዝያ"))
print(tokenizer("የቀን 7 ሰዓት አማርኛ ዜና ሚያዝያ"))
```

[out]:

```
119547

{'input_ids': [101, 100, 128, 100, 100, 100, 100, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

{'input_ids': [2, 1087, 388, 27, 1744, 2155, 1135, 5252, 3], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

{'input_ids': [101, 128730, 120760, 128, 128891, 121948, 135152, 135435, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

## Adding vocabs from one tokenizer to another

```
from datasets import load_dataset

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

# pick the model type
tokenizer1 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
tokenizer2 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")

print("Before adding roberta:", len(tokenizer1))

tokens_in_roberta_not_in_bert = set(tokenizer2.vocab).difference(tokenizer.vocab)
tokenizer1.add_tokens(list(tokens_in_roberta_not_in_bert))

print("After adding roberta:", len(tokenizer1))


model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

[out]:

```
Before adding roberta: 119547
After adding roberta: 162769
```

---

## Direct Answer to OP

To answer the question with the desired output in the original post (OP):

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

old_tokenizer_1 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

old_tokenizer_1.add_tokens(['foobarzz', 'helloworld'])
print(old_tokenizer_1( ['foobarzz', 'helloworld'] ))
```

[out]:

```
{'input_ids': [[0, 50265, 2], [0, 50266, 2]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]}
```

Comment: For a comprehensive list of emoji you probably need both [emoji-sequences.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/latest/emoji-sequences.txt) and [emoji-zwj-sequences.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/latest/emoji-zwj-sequences.txt).